# Скрыть код внутри функций Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Всем привет, как скрыть код внутри функций в netbeans ?

То есть там можно скрывать код нажав на плюсик слева от названия функции, тем самым остается только имя функции а все что внутри скрывается внутрь.
Мне надо сделать тоже самое только со всеми функциями сразу, так как функций много, знает кто как это сделать ? не нашел в мануале

Answer (score 4):

Нужная мне комбинация для минимизирования всех функций оказалась :

`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`-`

Скроет весь код внутри функций, и оставит только названия, при желании можно развернуть код и редактировать.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте custom code folding

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="user-description">
   ...любой код...
// </editor-fold>
```

`editor-fold` - начало и конец folding-а.
`defaultstate` - код будет скрыт по умолчанию, если значение этого атрибута установлено в "collapsed", иначе код развёрнут.
`desc` - описание, которое отображается когда код скрыт.

Comment: а где это написать ?

Comment: Вы что прикалываетесь? Очевидно в коде. Это же однострочный комментарий. Комментарий  с открывающий тегом ставится в начале свёртываемого кода, закрывающий в конце.

Comment: а какое это отношение имеет к моему вопросу ?
мне нужна комбинация клавищ, либо что то наподобие которая скроет весь код внутри всех функций и оставит только имена функций, как если нажать на знак минуса слева от названия функции.

Comment: функций много, вместо того чтобы писать комментария я могу нажать на знак минуса у всех функций и они скроются, мне нужен вариант который быстро скроет весь код внутри всех функций и оставит только имена

Comment: все уже спасибо, сам нашел, пишу ответ может понадобится кому.